# Getting appropriate time for message

Tags: javascript, datetime, quickblox

Using quickblox I am able to receive a message from the javascript SDK on the other platform clients, however the timestamp sent from the web interface is always returning the same time, I noticed that the length of the returned timestamp is significantly shorter than the stamp received from IOS or android. I currently create a message object as follows:

```
var msg = {
    type: 'chat',
    body: box.val(),
    markable: 1,
    extension: {        
      date_sent : date.getTime(),
      save_to_history: 0,
      userId: user_id
    }   };
```

What is the correct way to put a timestamp on a message from the javascript SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new keyword for getting latest date time.

```
var msg = {
    type: 'chat',
    body: box.val(),
    markable: 1,
    extension: {        
      date_sent : new Date().getTime(),
      save_to_history: 0,
      userId: user_id
    }
};
```